# How to include write a php function that defines a variable that holds html and php?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to write a function that defines a variable with html markup, now within that html markup I need to include a php snippet that has to be passed through a hook then outputted to my browser. Within my span tags I need the php snippet to output correctly.

The php snippet is this

```
<?php gravity_form(1, true, true, false, '', true); ?>
```

My function is below notice how the php snippet is formatted, I need to find out how to properly format it.

```
    function html_fxcntab_hidden_gform() {

    $html_fxcntab_hidden_gform_div = "<span style= \"display:none\";> <?php gravity_form(1, true, true, false, '', true); ?> </span>";

    echo $html_fxcntab_hidden_gform_div;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'html_fxcntab_hidden_gform');
```

Thanks,

Michael Sablatura

Comment: use concatenation `'<span style="display:none;">' . myFunction(1,true,false) . '</span>';`

Comment: That doesn't work if `gravity_form` displays its output instead of returning it, which it probably does. He'd have to use output buffering; @Ignacio's answer is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function html_fxcntab_hidden_gform() {
?>
  <span style="display:none"> <?php gravity_form(1, true, true, false, '', true); ?> </span><?php
}
```

Comment: gotta hate on the `?><span` stuff, though. icky html with php code.